# looking at this code, it does not make sense. Any explaination?

Tags: java, android

I am currently creating an app that takes in parameters that would be displayed in lists and sublists.  For example:

```
Parent1:
 -child 1
 -child 2

Parent2:
 - child 1
 - child 2
```

However, what I cannot figure out, is how to implement this.. I found this snippet of code online that is supposed to do that.  It comes with tons of other code, so i cannot post all of it.
What I am trying to understand HOW the following code takes the inputs and puts them in the correct category.(look at the core for the specific question)

```
  public void setGroupData() {
      groupItem.add("TechNology");
      groupItem.add("Mobile");
      groupItem.add("Manufacturer");
      groupItem.add("Extras");
     }

     ArrayList<String> groupItem = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<Object> childItem = new ArrayList<Object>();

     public void setChildGroupData() {
      /**
       * Add Technology Data
       */
      ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
      child.add("Java");
      child.add("Drupal");
      child.add(".Net Framework");
      child.add("PHP");
      childItem.add(child);

      /**
       * Add Data For Mobile
       */
      child = new ArrayList<String>();
      child.add("Android");
      child.add("Window Mobile");
      child.add("iPHone");
      child.add("Blackberry");
      childItem.add(child);
      /**
       * Add Data For Manufacture
       */
      child = new ArrayList<String>();
      child.add("HTC");
      child.add("Apple");
      child.add("Samsung");
      child.add("Nokia");
      childItem.add(child);
      /**
       * Add Data For Extras
       */
      child = new ArrayList<String>();
      child.add("Contact Us");
      child.add("About Us");
      child.add("Location");
      child.add("Root Cause");
      childItem.add(child);
     }
```

What I ideally want to do is have a edittext asking for the parent name, then use that to add it to the list through the setGroupData() method.  However, I do not understand how the rest of the code works. I want to add individual children to a specific parent when i click on that parent. I am very new to Java, so if you could please explain this question and code to me it would be greatly appreciated.  If anyone could tell me HOW to implement what I am trying to di it would be even better.

TL;DR: How does the code know which section of parent to add thie child information to? I am very new to java and do not understand

Comment: They seem to be going by indexes. 0 = technology, 1 = mobile, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a list of 4 groups - `groupItem`.

It has a list of 4 lists, that each has 4 children - `childItem`.

So for each group, there's a list of children:

```
Log.e("TAG", "Group 1: " + groupItem.get(0));
Log.e("TAG", "Group 1's children: " + childItem.get(0).toString());
```

Comment: thank you.  How would you suggest I implement my method of asking for input after clikcing on a specific parent?  I will add the parent to the grooupitem list through edittext, but how would you do anything else? like getting the index position of the parent to add the child to it?